# PHP trouble converting encoded Hebrew (ISO-8891-8-i) string back to Hebrew characters

Tags: php, encoding, hebrew

The subject of the email that I am working with is:

```
=?iso-8859-8-i?B?4gnjCeQJ5QnmCecJ6AnpCeoJ6wnsCe0J7w==?=
```

However, no combination of decoding (or `mb_convert_encoding`) seems to return it to looking like

```
בגדהוזחטיךכלםמן
```

I am noticing that `ISO-8891-8-i` seems to be missing from some of PHP's docs, but I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
// fix for logical/visual order encodings, e.g. iso-8859-8-i; PHP doesn't support conversion from these encodings so we just drop the ordering part of the encoding string
    if ( stripos($from_encoding, 'iso-8859-8') !== false )
    {
        $from_encoding = 'iso-8859-8';
    }
```

It's the `-i` portion mb_convert_encoding doesn't like.